# How to limit any user from viewing File revision history - Team Foundation server

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, tfs

I want to create an user in online team foundation server. but i need to block user to get lastest of web.config file or user unable to view the revision history. Your kind support is required

Comment: What's the online team foundations server？Which one you are working on ,the on-premise TFS such as TFS2017 or [VSTS(online)](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/)?

Comment: Visual studio team foundation [link](https://visualstudio.com)

Comment: Are you using GIT or TFVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to restrict a user view file revision history to force him "get the lateset". There is no such permission.

You could block users to get files from source control through permission. Right-click a folder/file in Source Control Explorer and go to **Properties -> Security** you can manage permissions right down to the folder/branch/file level.

[image]

For more details about permission in TFS, please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbsptfvc-object-level).

Answer (score 0):

If object file is on TFS version control, you can add a security policy for it, from right click menu: Advanced->Security on Source control explorer for specific users or groups.